# Simulink blocks display order

Tags: matlab, block, simulink

The functions "Send to Back" and "Bring to Front" are available by doing right click on a Simulink block => Arrange.
Is there any solution to access these functions programmatically.
The aim is to send to back or bring to front a block by using matlab script.

Thanks for help.

Comment: As far as I know, it's not possible to do this programmatically (or at least if it is, it's not documented).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each Simulink block has a property named "ZOrder". Blocks with lower values appear behind blocks with higher values. Calling "Send to Back" sets a low and possibly negative value, calling "Bring to Front" sets a high and possibly positive value.

In order to simulate those two function you'll need to set your block's ZOrder to a value smaller/larger than any other block's ZOrder within the same system. Use `find_system` with SearchDepth set to 1 to identify these blocks.

Use these two calls to get and set the ZOrder:

```
get(block_handle, 'ZOrder');

set(block_handle, 'ZOrder', newValue);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help opticdelusion.
as you suggested, I used the **find_system** to retrieve all elements of my block diagram, then i search for the element who's 'ZOrder' is the lowest and apply the property **set_param(myBlock, 'ZOrder', lowestZOrder - 1)**.
I did the same for bring to front, by searching the max ZOrder and increasing it to apply to my block.
I didn't knew the existence of 'ZOrder' proprtty before, i think that this property is not documented.

Thanks.